Using List in an Optimisation Problem
I have been adding various constraints to an existing optimiser and came across an issue. My latest constraints requires me to determine a conditional cumulative sum per below. There was an error and I tried to use a simple example to determine if this code for the new constraint works (optimiser works well before adding this constraint). It turns out i will need to run this code 3 times before it finally works. Ie getting error the first and second time I run before getting a result.
I also noticed I needed 2 layers to "Total" for it to work.
Can someone please explain why - and what can I do to fix it.
Its to be a constraint in an optimiser if that means anything.
Thanks
testtable = 
 Table[If[n < 5, n, Total[Total[testtable[[1 ;; n - 2]]]]], {n, 1, 
   10}]


The right hand side is evaluated before an assignment to "testtable" is made. Therefore, testtable[[1 ;; n - 2]] creates an error.
To fix your code:
testtable = {};
Do[AppendTo[testtable, 
  If[n < 5, n, Total[Total[testtable[[1 ;; n - 2]]]]]], {n, 1, 10}]
testtable

{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68}


Thanks heaps - the code works by itself and really appreciate your helpbut somehow fails in an optimisation context. Do you expect a set up above to work in an optimisation problem? Specifically, I think I need Mathematica to recalculate the above each time it trials a potential solution and I have a feeling that it wont work in an "iterative" sense. The code seems to only work in a sequential context.

Sorry so maybe more precisely: 'Sol=NMinimise[{expense,constr},vari]', where 'constr = {testtable>5}'. I am still playing around with the code to see if I can incorporate the above but the fact that testtable is initiated as {} makes me think the above may not work in an optimisation context.

As you already know the first 4 elements, you may initialize testable to Range[4] and eliminate the If.
